# How to show a custom actionbar view from one fragment only

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have a requirement for my app that a custom action bar view be shown from one fragment only (the landing page fragment). The problem is that this action bar is appearing when the user navigates to other fragments. Is there a way to do this without disabling custom view on every fragment?

Thanks

Comment: use 'getActivity().getActionbar().hide()' to hide actionbar when nav to fragment that you do not want to show.

Comment: But I would have to write this in all fragments except for the landing page fragment. I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: Only for the landing fragment, use ''getActivity().getActionbar().show()'' in onAttach, and ''getActivity().getActionbar().hide()'' in onDetach.

Comment: maybe override 'onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden)' with show/hide actionbar is better idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this issue, only show actionbar for one fragment without show on all other fragments, solution could be very easy:

In your activity that hosts your fragments:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ... ...

    // for API >= 11
    getActionBar.hide();
    // for API < 11
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    ... ...
}
```

Then in the fragment that you want to show actionbar:

```
@Override
public void  onAttach(Activity activity){
    activity.getActionBar().show(); //getSupportActionBar() for API<11

}

@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
    if (hidden) {
       getActivity().getActionBar().hide(); //getSupportActionBar() for API<11
    } else {
       getActivity().getActionBar().show(); //getSupportActionBar() for API<11
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm just trying to suggest. Why not removing the action bar to all the fragments and just creating a single fragment (the landing page) with a custom action bar thru layout?

To remove ActionBar to all fragments, add this code to  tag:

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"`

Create a Layout with action bar for your landing page through xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rlMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlHeaderMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:padding="5dp" >


</RelativeLayout>
```