# Hide ActionBar title just for one activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

If I apply theme for whole application it hides ActionBar title successfully:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

**assign in manifest**:

```
    <application
    android:name="myapp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_bar_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

I need ActionBar title hidden just in **one activity**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
 ...other things...
</style>

<style name="MainActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

**setting this theme explicitly for one activity:**

```
<LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity"
   android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:theme="@style/MainActivityTheme">
```

and it still shows title in `MainActivity` `ActionBar`. I know how to hide the title in java, I need to know what I do wrong here in XML.

Comment: You just want to hide actionbar title or an actionbar?

Comment: Refer to the post [How to show a custom actionbar view from one fragment only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061940/how-to-show-a-custom-actionbar-view-from-one-fragment-only/28065244#28065244) to get idea

Comment: You can do this by the simple way. In your `onCreate` do this `getActionBar.hide();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the theme on your activity in the manifest.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:theme="@style/MainActivityTheme" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to create a sub-theme which hides the action bar:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

and then apply it to your activity in the manifest like so:

```
<activity android:name="NonActionBarActivity"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Using the dot notation (`AppTheme.NoActionBar`) makes this `NoActionBar` theme inherit everything from `AppTheme` and override the setting on `android:windowActionBar`. If you prefer you can explicitly note the parent:

```
<style name="AppThemeWithoutActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Also, if you're using the AppCompat libraries, you probably want to add a namespace-less version to the sub-theme.

```
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `actionbar title` then just **remove** `label` attribute from `<activity>` tag in your `manifest` file.

Such as,

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivityName"
        android:label="@string/title" />
```

And after removing,

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivityName" />
```

Done!