# Android each fragment with own actionbar

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, fragment

I've an MainActivity which displays different fragments. At the moment the MainActivity creates the actionbar for the app, so each fragment has the same actionbar. Now I want that some of the fragments don't show the actionbar, so if I open the fragment the MainActivity hide the actionbar and displayed the fragment. The problem is that hiding the actionbar and displaying a new fragment makes the app a bit laggy and the transaction isn't really good looking.

So is their a possibility to remove the actionbar completely from the MainActivity and each fragment creates their a own actionbar, so I don't need to show and hide the actionbar constantly? - if so how would I do this?

Comment: does this help => `<android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">` in `<application>` tag ?

Comment: Check my answer to the post [How to show a custom actionbar view from one fragment only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061940/how-to-show-a-custom-actionbar-view-from-one-fragment-only/28065244#28065244)

Answer (score 0):

in onCreate Of your fragment

```
 setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Then override

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_YOURMENU_FOR_FRAGMENT, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

in your fragment.